# Rust lib and bin sharing the same name, but having separate dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project `abc`, with a lib and a bin using it.
I want to have these three boxes checked:

- [ ] my binary has the file-name `abc`
- [ ] my library can be used by others as dependency `abc = "0.3"`
- [ ] lib and bin have different dependencies

Two scenarios, none of which I got to where I want it.

### 1. Simple

So far, I had it **all in one folder***,
with structure:

```
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs
```

*Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[package]
name = "abc"
version = "0.3.0"
# ...

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0" # for bin
clap = "4.0" # for bin
log = "0.4" # for both
thiserror = "1.0" # for lib
```

This gives me:

- [x] my binary has the file-name `abc`
- [x] my library can be used by others as dependency `abc = "0.3"`
- [ ] lib and bin have different dependencies

### 2. Workspaces

Now, to be able to have separate dependencies,
I try it with workspaces,
with structure:

```
├── Cargo.toml
├── bin
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── lib
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

*Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[workspace]
members = [
   "lib",
   "bin",
]
```

*lib/Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[package]
name = "abc"
version = "0.3.0"
# ...

[dependencies]
log = "0.4"
thiserror = "1.0"
```

*bin/Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[package]
name = "abc-bin"
version = "0.3.0"
# ...

[dependencies]
abc = { path = "../lib" }
anyhow = "1.0"
clap = "4.0"
log = "0.4"
```

This gives me:

- [ ] my binary has the file-name `abc` 
  -> it is `abc-bin`
- [x] my library can be used by others as dependency `abc = "0.3"`
- [x] lib and bin have different dependencies

Or alternatively this,
if I change the packages names to `abc-lib` and `abc` (for the binary):

- [x] my binary has the file-name `abc`
- [ ] my library can be used by others as dependency `abc = "0.3"` 
  -> it is `abc-lib = "0.3"`
- [x] lib and bin have different dependencies

### Question

How can I get all 3 boxes checked?

NOTE: Cargo understandably does not allow the two packages to have the same name.